# Git: Remove deleted files from work-tree

Tags: git

I have this cron job running to update my website and it's working:

```
*/10 * * * * cd /var/www/mysite; git pull;
git --work-tree=/var/www/html/mysite.com/public_html/
 --git-dir=/var/www/mysite/.git checkout -f
```

I noticed that when I run 'git status' it shows a lot of deleted: files and when I check my running site I can see that files I deleted in commit is not deleted from site. I was told to run 'git add -u .' and this makes all the deleted files green deleted: instead of red deleted:. But after the cron job has run again I'm back to same status.

How to get a git commit with one changed file and one deleted file to work in this cronjob so that the file I want to delete is also deleted in the working website?

Comment: If you see things when you run `git status`, this means these things are not committed, and thus modification is not in a commit and as a result `git pull` won't remove these files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Two work-trees means you need two index files

The problem in this case stems from the fact that there is only one *index* (aka staging area, aka cache), but two *work trees*.

Remember that for `git checkout` there are three items of interest:

- a *commit* that you intend to check out;
- the index, which (among its other duties) acts as a way for Git to keep track of the work-tree: this is its *cache* aspect; and
- the *work tree*, which is the set of files in normal, non-Gitty format that the rest of the operating system can deal with.

Let's take a look at your `cron` command:

> ```
> cd /var/www/mysite; git pull;
> ```

For this part to work, there must be a Git repository in `/var/www/mysite/.git` with a corresponding work-tree in `/var/www/mysite/`.  The index—there is only one; it's in `/var/www/mysite/.git/index`—caches what's in the work-tree.

> ```
> git --work-tree=/var/www/html/mysite.com/public_html/
> --git-dir=/var/www/mysite/.git checkout -f
> ```

For this part to work, there is a Git repository in `/var/www/mysite/.git` (as we just saw) with a corresponding work-tree in `/var/www/html/mysite.com/public_html/`.  The index—there is only one—caches what's in the work-tree.

But there are two work-trees, with only one index inside the one shared Git repository.  The one cache is trying to keep track of—and speed up—two different directories that it thinks are just one directory.  So things eventually go awry.  (The exact pattern of going-awry is quite tricky since the cache records a lot of OS-level time stamps and is automatically invalidated under various conditions, so that it all works correctly *as long as there's only one work-tree for that cache*.)

#### There are multiple solutions

One simple solution is to destroy, and then let Git rebuild, the index.

The *cache aspect* of the index is there only to speed things up.  This means you can destroy the index entirely and then rebuild it.  This isn't really a great solution because the index has *three* roles: besides its cache aspect, it's also where you build up your next commit, and where you resolve conflicted merges.  Destroying the index works *only* when its only active role is "speed things up".

A more complex solution is to use more than one index file.

There are multiple ways to implement this second solution, too, though.  You can set an environment variable, `GIT_INDEX_FILE`, to point to a path name, and Git will use that as its index file.  Hence instead of just:

```
git --work-tree=/var/www/html/mysite.com/public_html/
--git-dir=/var/www/mysite/.git checkout -f
```

you can have the last step read:

```
GIT_INDEX_FILE=/var/www/mysite/.git/index.public_html
git --work-tree=/var/www/html/mysite.com/public_html/
--git-dir=/var/www/mysite/.git checkout -f
```

(all as one big line—I broke it up here for display purposes).  The main drawback is that you must remember to set this `GIT_INDEX_FILE` variable *every time* you use it this way.

Another way is to use `git worktree add`, available since Git 2.5 or so.  This makes additional work-trees, and—being built in to Git—each work-tree comes with its own index.  The main drawback here is that each work-tree must be on a *different branch*, or use "detached HEAD" mode.  The latter is what you would want for this case: instead of `git checkout -f`, you would `git checkout --detach master`.  To do this, do a one-time `git worktree add` to create the second work-tree (see [the `git worktree` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-worktree.html)), and then change the final `git checkout` to:

```
cd /var/www/html/mysite.com/public_html; git checkout -f --detach master
```

A minor secondary drawback is that this added work-tree (in `/var/www/html/mysite.com/public_html`) will have a `.git` file in it.  Note that this is not a directory, it's just a file.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for not following up and thank you for the answer.
It helped me a lot!

I ended up with the following command and droped the cron job.

```
sudo bash
su www-data -s /bin/bash
cd /var/www/mydomain
git fetch https://bitbucket.org/myaccount/mydomain.git
[Login to BitBucket]
git pull
git status
git --work-tree=/var/www/html/mydomain.dk/public_html/ --git-dir=/var/www/mydomain/.git checkout -f
git status
exit # From www-data user
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i see a mistake in your cron. If your first pull and then checkout its possible that you have modified files and you get an conflict if you pull. You should first checkout and then pull your changes.

To commit everything you can use `git add -A` that command adds changed and deleted files. Then you can make a normal commit if needed.

Comment: I change, delete and commit in my local developer environment and then push all to my Bitbucket repository. When pushed, this is working master and my cron job just have to pull from my repository to update site with my changes including deleted files. Changes gets to my site but I see if I delete a file, it's not deleted from --work-tree.

Answer (score 0):

Do check whether you have really deleted those files. Once you are sure that you have deleted those files, do the following

- `git rm -r --cached .`
- `git add -A`
- `git commit -m "Your commit message`
- `git push origin branch_name`